# a wider \Downarrow

Tags: symbols

I want to write a wider `\Downarrow`, I couldn't find one in any package I know, so I tried with:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}    
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\Big\Downarrow
%\Large\Downarrow
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

but it seems that it only gets longer, I want it wider: how can I do that?

**Edit**: to be clearer I add an image:

[image]

on the left: what I have
on the right: what I want.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I am sorry I forgot it. Now I added it

Comment: With other words: It should be 'thicker'?

Comment: @mattiav27 L'inglese *large* non ha specifiche connessioni con la larghezza, ma è solo “grande”. Per “largo” c'è *wide* o, per uno spessore, *thick*. Quindi *wider* o *thicker*.

Comment: @egreg grazie: correggo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way to do that while also respecting a correct spacing around the symbol:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{relsize}
\newcommand\wideDownarrow{\mathrel{\scalebox{1.2}[1]{$\Downarrow$}}}

\begin{document}

\[ A\Downarrow B \wideDownarrow C \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

- `\scalebox` scales according to ratio --> Perhaps not wanted
- `\resizebox` uses a width and height information -> distortion is possible.

---

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{graphicx}%

\begin{document}
 \begin{equation}
   \Big\Downarrow  % No?
   \scalebox{1.5}{$\Downarrow$} % No!
   \resizebox{0.05\textwidth}{11pt}{$\Downarrow$} % perhaps?
   \resizebox{0.2\textwidth}{11pt}{$\Downarrow$} % weird!
 \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A TikZ based approach might be better in this case, in order not to thicken the strokes. Assuming one really wants it, of course.

Comment: @egreg: For sure, yes... As long it's not clear, it's just one way.